# Как сменить адрес репозиторий Git в Visual Studio для отправки обновлений по новому адресу

Tags: visual-studio, git, github, git-commit, repository

Такая проблема: сменился адрес репозитория проекта Git, как теперь настроить конфигурацию и Visual Studio, чтобы все обновления отправлялись по новому адресу? Потому что сейчас при push пишет: unable to access “старый адрес”.
Я не очень опытен в работе с Git, поэтому нужна помощь.

Answer (score 1):

Самый простой известный мне способ - откройте папку с проектом и в скрытой папке .git найдите файл config. И там Вы найдете ключи url/fetch где будут Ваши старые адреса. Поменяйте их так, что бы они указывали на новые. Не забудьте перед этим сохранить себе этот файл куда то, на всякий случай.

Более "корректный способ".

Проверьте текущие пути

```
git remote -v
```

Установите новый путь

```
git remote set-url origin https://git-repo/new-repository.git
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь